# Pre-condition checking in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-class

I have a `typescript` class where there are methods for checking the variables type.
How do I determine at the beginning of the `doProcess()` which method to use for processing the following?

```
class MyClass {

public static arr : any[] = [];

// main method
public static doProcess(object : object , justForObjects : boolean = false){
    if (justForObjects){
        // here should specify which checking method use in *** line
    } else {

    }

    for (let key in object){
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if (/* *** */){
                MyClass.doProcess(object[key] , justObjects)
            } else {
                MyClass.arr.push(object[key])
            }
        }
    }

return MyClass.arr;

}

 // check variables type methods
 private static is_object(value : any){
     return !!(typeof value === 'object' && !(value instanceof Array) && value);
 }
 private static is_object_or_array(value : any){
     return !!(typeof value === 'object' && value);
 }

}

let object = {
 'main color' : 'black',
 'other colors' : {
     'front color' : 'purple',
     'back color' : 'yellow',
     'inside colors' : {
         'top color' : 'red',
         'bottom color' : 'green'
     }
 }
}

MyClass.doProcess(object , true);
```

I know it can be done in the same for loop (as below), but I would like to find a way to do it first.

```
    for (let key in object){
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if (justForObjects){
                if (MyClass.is_object(object[key])){
                    // do something
                }
            } else {
                if (MyClass.is_object_or_array(object[key])){
                    // do something else
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can be simply assigned to variables, i.e.:

```
public static doProcess(obj : object , justForObjects : boolean = false) {

    var check_fn = justForObjects ? MyClass.is_object : MyClass.is_object_or_array;

    for (let key in obj) {
        if (check_fn(obj[key])) ...
    }

}

 // check variables type methods
 private static is_object(value : any) : boolean { ... }
 private static is_object_or_array(value : any) : boolean { ... }
```

Comment: Note also that it would perhaps be better to configure the class in its constructor (i.e. `var c = new MyClass(true); // just for objects`, and then have a clean interface for processing the actual item (`c.doProcess(obj); // only one parameter`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think bind can be used instead of a variable? How do you do it right if you agree?

Comment: @ali.rezaie: I am not sure what `bind` would do here, can you provide an example? This is a simple approach to a simple problem, but as I wrote above, it's possible that there would be a better approach altogether if you posted the actual code with the actual problem (it's hard to guess what `MyClass.doProcess` means). My suggestion would be to create a full working example and post it on codereview.stackexchange.com. Your colors example suggests that it should be processed recursively like mentioned in the other answer, but it's impossible to say without knowing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I edited my question and completed the doProcess() method.
As you can see, this method returns all the values of the objects in an array and it also includes nests values

Answer (score 1):

#### See if a recursive method helps you:

```
interface CustomObject {
  [path: string]: ObjectValue;
}

type ObjectValue = string | CustomObject | CustomObject[];

class MyClass {
  /**
   *
   *
   * @recursive
   */
  public static doProcess(
    object: CustomObject,
    justForObjects: boolean = false
  ) {
    for (const key in object) {
      const value = object[key];

      if (this.isObjectOrArray(value, justForObjects)) {
        this.doProcess(value as CustomObject, justForObjects);
        continue;
      } else {
        // do something;
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  /**
   *
   *
   * Check is object or array
   */
  private static isObjectOrArray(
    value: ObjectValue,
    justForObjects: boolean = false
  ) {
    // objects and arrays
    if (!justForObjects) return !!(typeof value === "object" && value);

    if (Array.isArray(value)) throw new TypeError("Array value not allowed");

    // only objects
    return !!(typeof value === "object" && !(value instanceof Array) && value);
  }
}

let object = {
  "main color": "black",
  "other colors": {
    "front color": "purple",
    "back color": "yellow",
    "inside colors": {
      "top color": "red",
      "bottom color": "green"
    }
  }
} as CustomObject;

MyClass.doProcess(object, true);
```